# What builds the Ubuntu Server iso?

Tags: server, iso

Asking because I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. What builds the Ubuntu server ISOs and how does it run. Say I want to bundle a custom installer with a custom squashfs as part of making my own distro. Outside of tools like Cubic, how is the Ubuntu server image made? What tool generates it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what Canonical themselves use, but I have used the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization in the past and they have worked great in building my own ISOs.

Comment: ISOs and packages are built on launchpad, be it for QA testing (and ultimate release) OR just packages for PPAs.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NewReleaseCycleProcess

Comment: "*The ISO images and the building of the final ISO is done on a machine called Nusakan, named after the second brightest star in the Corona Borealis. . Canonical employees have direct SSH access to this machine and can use it to manually trigger builds, as well as doing final publishing.*"  .. copy/pasted from Lubuntu instructions on the builds... The machine does all ISOs for all teams (main Ubuntu and desktop flavors)   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage